# is there a maximum number of events you can track in Google Analytics for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, flurry

Thanks in advance for the assistance. I recently ran into an issue with a clients app using Flurry Analytics. There is a maximum number of 300 events that can be tracked (each event can have a total of 10 different paramaters) I need to track more then 300 events for this client.

Does Google Analytics have a maximum number of events that can be tracked?

(the reason for the high number of tracked events for those who are curious is because the client has a database of about 15000 products, and wants to know how users are interacting with the products, additionally they want to track the search terms that users are searching for, thus the need for a HUGE number of events to be tracked....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a limit of 10 million hits (could be events, page views etc) per month. Read specifics at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/limits-quotas. This is the free version. The Premium version supports higher data limits. https://www.google.com/analytics/360-suite/#?modal_active=none

Comment: Thank you! I am thinking 10 million hits should be sufficient. :-)

Comment: Worth noting that there's also a 500 hits per session limit http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

There is also a 10 event (`_trackEvent`) limit over a 5 second period.

Answer (score 0):

Thought it might be helpful to clarify, considering the changes that Google made in Oct '12.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/limits-quotas

> 10 million hits per month per web property - If you go over this limit, the Google Analytics team might contact you and ask you upgrade to Premium or implement client sampling to reduce the amount of data being sent to Google Analytics.

...

> **ga.js or Legacy Libraries**
>   This applies to ga.js, mobile snippets and any other legacy tracking library.
>   500 hits per session not including ecommerce (item and transaction hit types)
>   If you go over this limit, additional hits will not be processed for that session.

...

> **ga.js**
>   Each web property starts with 10 hits that are replenished at 1 hit per second. Applies only to event type hits.
>
> **analytics.js**
>   Each web property starts with 20 hits that are replenished at 2 hit per second. Applies to All hits.
>
> **Android SDK**
>   For each tracker instance on a device, each app instance starts with 60 hits that are replenished at 1 hit every 2 seconds. Applies to All hits.
>
> **iOS SDK**
>   Each property starts with 60 hits that are replenished at 1 hit every 2 seconds. Applies to All hits.